# Can I use semantic metadata to establish relationships between files?

Tags: linux, rdf, sparql

It is possible to tag files in order to establish relationships between them in Linux via the Nepomuk ontology? For example, an essay stored in file `a.pdf` contradicts what is stated in another essay stored in file `b.pdf`. Can this be expressed in RDF? How?

It would be useful if I could then make a SPARQL query (I know GNOME Tracker can do this) to search for that specific information stored as RDF in the files.

Now, I can only tag my files with specific keywords, but I cannot describe the relationships between them.

I'm really new to RDF, SPARQL and Nepomuk ontology, so maybe I'm talking nonsense, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this.